# How to use Django trans tag {% trans "some string" %} in Kendo UI Template

Tags: django, kendo-ui, django-templates

I have HTML template which is using Kendo UI template. I am facing issues if I use {% trans %} tag under Kendo UI template. If the tag is {% trans "some string" %}, when I load the HTML page, instead of showing "some string" on the UI, it shows {% trans "some string" %}. The code snippet is shown below.

```
 # if (data.is_reanalysis_template) { #
       {% trans "Name" %}: #= data.planDisplayedName #
 # } #
```

The output of the above code is

```
{% trans "Name" %}: XYZ
```

instead of

```
Name: XYZ
```

I referred to Kendo UI [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/templates/overview) to see how to escape the tags. It was not very useful. Can someone please let me know how to fix this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use Django template syntax in your static files. Read this, if you want to use i18n in your javascripts:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/i18n/#translations-and-javascript